# jQuery datatable with BelongsToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, datatables, eloquent

I am using https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables library to integrate datatable into laravel.

So I have this query:

```
public function query()
{
    $query = Auth::user()->cars_as_dispatcher()->whereIn('status', [3, 4, 5])->orderBy('missions.id', 'desc');

    return $this->applyScopes($query);
}
```

with the relation:

```
public function cars_as_dispatcher()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Car', 'dispatcher_cars', 'uid', 'car_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

The error I get is:

```
 Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'
```

because the query return 2 id columns:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Both `User` table and `Car` table has `id` attribute. When you execute belongsToMany, it will execute join but there are 2 id attribute in result => error. If you using uid, why you still using id?

Comment: So how to remove? To delete the id column from the pivot table?